# Adding items to ListBox using Form Designer in VBA (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm having issues trying to programmatically add items to a

```
Form.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.ListBox.1")
```

I've tried using the method

```
Form.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1").AddItem "Item"
```

And while this doesn't return a debug error, the item also doesn't appear in the form.

---

[image]

---

Here is the full class module, from which I use the method AddList()

https://github.com/thorlindberg/thorlindberg/blob/main/programmatic-userform/UserInterface.bas

And here is the macro that calls it to generate the Form

https://github.com/thorlindberg/thorlindberg/blob/main/programmatic-userform/Example.bas

Comment: You can't do that, as far as I know. There is nowhere to store list items at design time.

Comment: You cannot store list items at the design time in this way. But you can create the `UserForm_Initialize` event, where the items can be added. Practically the form will show with the loaded list box. I can show you how to proceed...

Comment: Your code works for me (when I change the function createForm (leave identifier = "Form1" out and turn around identifier = .Properties("Name") ))  add the list later: in your Function RenderForm: With VBA.UserForms.Add(identifier)
   .Controls("Listbox").List = Array("Apple", "Banana", "Clementine")
   .Show
   End With

Answer (score 3):

As I said in my above comment, you cannot add items using `FormDesigner` in the way you try. But you can write in (the same) code the `UserForm_Initialize` event, able to add the necessary items:

```
Sub createUserFormListBoxWithItems()
    Dim frm As Object
    Set frm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_MSForm) '3

    With frm
        .Properties("Caption") = "MyTestForm"
        .Properties("Width") = 300
        .Properties("Height") = 200
        .Properties("Name") = "frmLBTest"
    End With
    
    With frm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.ListBox.1")
        .Name = "MyListB"
        .top = frm.Properties("Height") - 150
        .left = 10: .width = 100: .height = 50
    End With
    
    Dim i As Long, myItem As String
    frm.CodeModule.InsertLines 2, "Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()" '2 for the case of automatically inserting of Option Explicit

    myItem = "MyItem"
    For i = 3 To 5
        frm.CodeModule.InsertLines i, "    Me.Controls(""MyListB"").AddItem """ & myItem & i & """"
    Next i
    frm.CodeModule.InsertLines i, "End Sub"

    VBA.UserForms.Add(frm.Name).Show
End Sub
```

If you try playing with the code more than once, VBA does not accept the same `UserForm` name, even if you delete it before running the code. It remains somewhere in Excel as a used name. When I play with such forms creation I am using a function which previously change the form name and `Remove` it from the project only after that. For instance, the next piece of code will use the list box `list` property to load items using an array. It will have a line calling the above mentioned function:

```
Sub createUserFormListBoxWithItems_2()
    Dim frm As Object
     
    removeForm "frmLBTest"
    Set frm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_MSForm) '3
 
    With frm
        .Properties("Caption") = "MyTestForm"
        .Properties("Width") = 300
        .Properties("Height") = 200
        .Properties("Name") = "frmLBTest"
    End With
    
    With frm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.ListBox.1")
        .Name = "MyListB"
        .top = frm.Properties("Height") - 150
        .left = 10: .width = 100: .height = 50
    End With
    
    With frm.CodeModule
        .InsertLines 2, "Private arrItems" '2 for the case of automatically inserting of Option Explicit
        .InsertLines 3, "Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()"
        .InsertLines 4, "    arrItems = Split(""Apple,Banana,Clementine"", "","")"
        .InsertLines 5, "    Me.Controls(""MyListB"").list = arrItems"
        .InsertLines 6, "End Sub"
    End With
    
    VBA.UserForms.Add(frm.Name).Show
End Sub

Sub removeForm(frmName As String)
 Dim i As Long, strName As String
 If Not formExists(frmName) Then Exit Sub

 strName = "TestName"
tryAgain:
 On Error Resume Next
  frm.Name = strName
  If err.Number = 75 Then 'a previously used name...
     err.Clear                    'clear the error
        strName = strName & i: i = i + 1       'increment the new string
        frm.Name = strName: GoTo tryAgain  'test the new name again
  End If
 On Error GoTo 0
 ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove frm
End Sub
```